# show ajax response in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to show my ajax response in dropdown.I am not sure how can i do this
I have this result in console and i want to show them just like google autocomplete address and on clicking one of them insert into input search field as shown in picture[image]

api response:

```
{description: 'Avenida de América, Madrid, Spain', matched_substrings: Array(1), place_id: 'EiJBdmVuaWRhIGRlIEFtw6lyaWNhLCBNYWRyaWQsIFNwYWluIi…WJBAvQg0RQvmLCEvZGOESFAoSCYE8CoCXKUINEWkijGHB3jbE', reference: 'EiJBdmVuaWRhIGRlIEFtw6lyaWNhLCBNYWRyaWQsIFNwYWluIi…WJBAvQg0RQvmLCEvZGOESFAoSCYE8CoCXKUINEWkijGHB3jbE', structured_formatting: {…}, …}
autocomplete:39 1 {description: 'Avenida Paulista - Bela Vista, São Paulo - State of São Paulo, Brazil', matched_substrings: Array(1), place_id: 'EkdBdmVuaWRhIFBhdWxpc3RhIC0gQmVsYSBWaXN0YSwgU8Ojby…trIWc6UEWp3yfIxlJ_VEhQKEglhPUZWt1nOlBFkCfT35tHzCQ', reference: 'EkdBdmVuaWRhIFBhdWxpc3RhIC0gQmVsYSBWaXN0YSwgU8Ojby…trIWc6UEWp3yfIxlJ_VEhQKEglhPUZWt1nOlBFkCfT35tHzCQ', structured_formatting: {…}, …}
autocomplete:39 2 {description: 'Airport Drive, Oakland, CA, USA', matched_substrings: Array(1), place_id: 'Eh9BaXJwb3J0IERyaXZlLCBPYWtsYW5kLCBDQSwgVVNBIi4qLA…G2giFj4ARtshexOmLHO4SFAoSCQPtqiiLfYWAEWeTdTXVFbRx', reference: 'Eh9BaXJwb3J0IERyaXZlLCBPYWtsYW5kLCBDQSwgVVNBIi4qLA…G2giFj4ARtshexOmLHO4SFAoSCQPtqiiLfYWAEWeTdTXVFbRx', structured_formatting: {…}, …}
autocomplete:39 3 {description: 'Agra - Lucknow Expressway, Khargua, Deeg, Uttar Pradesh, India', matched_substrings: Array(1), place_id: 'Ej5BZ3JhIC0gTHVja25vdyBFeHByZXNzd2F5LCBLaGFyZ3VhLC…md7a3Q5EfLivNhidG9FEhQKEglZDb8j5fp1OREYbxU6obqUwg', reference: 'Ej5BZ3JhIC0gTHVja25vdyBFeHByZXNzd2F5LCBLaGFyZ3VhLC…md7a3Q5EfLivNhidG9FEhQKEglZDb8j5fp1OREYbxU6obqUwg', structured_formatting: {…}, …}
autocomplete:39 4 {description: 'Andheri Railway Station East Northern Overpass, Railway Colony, Andheri East, Mumbai, Maharashtra', matched_substrings: Array(1), place_id: 'EmFBbmRoZXJpIFJhaWx3YXkgU3RhdGlvbiBFYXN0IE5vcnRoZX…_0dPJ5zsRcFUI8HcXv_ESFAoSCYsfczDSyec7EfPGJy6AiyF_', reference: 'EmFBbmRoZXJpIFJhaWx3YXkgU3RhdGlvbiBFYXN0IE5vcnRoZX…_0dPJ5zsRcFUI8HcXv_ESFAoSCYsfczDSyec7EfPGJy6AiyF_', structured_formatting: {…}, …}
autocomplete:37 5
autocomplete:39 0 {description: 'Asghar Ali Shah Cricket Stadium Shahrah Noor Jahan, Block C North Nazimabad Town, Karachi, Pakistan', matched_substrings: Array(1), place_id: 'ChIJVxARAok_sz4RCZ0uUfWUZow', reference: 'ChIJVxARAok_sz4RCZ0uUfWUZow', structured_formatting: {…}, …}
```

This is my input field and ajax response

```
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" class="form-control">
```

ajax response:

```
   success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.predictions.length);
                $.each(data.predictions, function(address,value) {
                   console.log(address,value);
                   alert(value.description)
                    alert(value.place_id)

                });
            }
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Just create `<option>` elements from the objects, and append them to the dropdown.

Comment: i think append will appends all the results. My response returns 5 result each time user type something. so i need only this 5 result

Comment: you can use `typeahead.js`. See more http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: is this possible with simple css design?

Comment: @David Clear the dropdown before appending what it returns.

Comment: @Barmar, will you please write code how to do that. Thanks

Comment: I'll help you fix your code, I won't write it for you.

Comment: If you can't do it yourself, use a library like jQuery-UI Autocomplete or Typeahead.js.

Comment: var div_data = "<option value=" + value.description + ">" + value.description + "</option>";
    
$(div_data).appendTo('#autocomplete');

Comment: alternatively, you could try https://select2.org/

Answer (score -1):

update code here hopes this will help you to achieve what you want to.

```html
   
<link 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 

src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
});
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```